# Making OS X ping command show "request timeout" in output if no ICMP replies received

Tags: macos, mac, networking, command-line

How can I make the ping command in Mac OS X show "request timeout" in its output if no ICMP replies are received, similar to what the Windows ping command does?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
ping -v host.com
```

Comment: This doesn't add a time out.

Comment: Andrew S answered my question. The following is my trial. Thanks
--
$ ping -v 192.168.97.3
PING 192.168.97.3 (192.168.97.3): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: Host is down
ping: sendto: Host is down
ping: sendto: Host is down

Comment: Richard H, that isn't what he asked. I think you misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a time out with the -t option. e.g.

```
 ping -t 5 microsoft.com
```

This will exit after five seconds wether the target is alive or not.

Comment: The question was for a way to provide request timeout feedback versus asking how to provide a timeout. The accepted answer does that although adding a timeout also works. It seems that newer versions of OSX provide additional feedback without any additional parameters.